# Use PySpark to set min and max date off of json input

Tags: pyspark

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
root
 |-- Report_Entry: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Account: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AccountCategory: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AccountCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AccountType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AccountingDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to get the min and max dates from the AccountingDate, but so far I get an error about not being able to resolve AccountingDate.  The outputted schema has AccountingDate as a string and I'm not sure if that's an issue? I'm using the following PySpark code:

```
dfBronze = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(SourceFilePath)
dfBronze.printSchema()
maxDate = dfBronze.agg({"AccountingDate": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
print (maxDate)
```

And the error is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2997.agg.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "AccountingDate" among (Report_Entry);
```

Comment: You need to `explode` the `Report_Entry` first

Answer (score 1):

You need to `explode` the `Report_Entry` first.
Try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
dfBronze = (
    dfBronze
    .withColumn('ReportEntry', f.explode(f.col('Report_Entry')))
    .select('Report_Entry.*')
    .select(f.max('AccountingDate'))
)
```

Comment: When I run the syntax above, I keep getting invalid syntax on the next statement.  The following is an exact cut and paste of that code: 
`import pyspark.sql.functions as f
dfBronze = (
    dfBronze
    .withColumn('ReportEntry', f.explode(f.col('Report_Entry')))
    .select('Report_Entry.*')
    .select(f.max('AccountingDate'))

dfBronze.show()`

Comment: Do you get syntax error on this code or something that's happening after this?